# Excel Multiple value autofill

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to find the excel formula where in Sheet2!A2 (Here-3) is filled any from Sheet1!A, it will give all values from Sheet1!B in Sheet2!B.

[image]

Thanks & Regards,
Rakib

Comment: You question is not clear. Explain more details.

Comment: If you put a value to Sheet2 - A2 (Which is present on Sheet1 - A1:A10) - The values present in Sheet1 - B1:B10 - will appear automatically in sheet2 column B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to filter data based on condition. Following formula will filter data on same sheet.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$7)/($A$1:$A$7=$D$2),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

For `Sheet2` use following formula.

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$7)/(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$7=$A$1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It works but Only for 500 rows, it takes huge time with high CPU

Comment: It will work thousands of rows but it bit slower as `AGGREGATE()` is an array formula. In this situation `VBA` is best choice.

Comment: Many thanks for you reply. Could it be in another way like - Taking the first and last value using VLOOKUP and then generate the middle numbers?

Comment: There may other approaches but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use the V/Hlookup functions for specific data, or else just use the = sign